# Why the answers are not displayed when the counter ends

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am novice in javascript. I will consult you for something. When the counter ends, I try to make the answer button work, that is, the results are displayed. I would really appreciate if you can help.
and when answering the questions we perceive it as wrong when we leave any questions blank I want to show the blank value in the answer.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>QUIZ</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function cevapla()
{
 var soruSayisi=3;
 var gelenCevap = new Array();
 var dogruCevap = new Array("C",);
 var dogru=0;
 var yanlis=0;
 var cevap=0;
 var rapor="";
     
 for(i=1; i <= soruSayisi; i++){ 
  var secenekler=document.getElementsByName("s"+i);
  for(j=0; j < secenekler.length; j++){
   if(secenekler[j].checked){               
    if(secenekler[j].value==dogruCevap[i-1]){
     cevap=1;
    }else{
    cevap=0;
    }   
    if(cevap){
     rapor +=i+". Soru için cevabınız: "+secenekler[j].value+", Doğru <br />";
    }else{
     rapor +=i+". Soru için cevabınız: "+secenekler[j].value+", YANLIŞ, Doğru Cevap: "+dogruCevap[i-1]+"<br />";
    }
     gelenCevap.push(secenekler[j].value);
   }
  }
 }  
    
 for(k=0; k < soruSayisi; k++){
  if(gelenCevap[k]==dogruCevap[k]){
   dogru++;
  }else{
   yanlis++;
  }
 }
 rapor +="Sonuç: "+dogru+" Doğru, "+yanlis+" Yanlış"+"<br />";
 document.getElementById('rapor').innerHTML=rapor;
 }
 
 var deger;
var saniye=10;
function saniyeDurdur()
  {
    window.clearInterval(deger);
  }
function saniyeBaslat()

{
    saniye --;
    if(saniye >=0){
        document.getElementById('saniye').innerHTML=saniye;
    }else{
        window.clearInterval(deger);
        document.getElementById('uyari').innerHTML="Süreniz bitti! Sınav Bitmiştir Geçmiş Olsun";
        rapor +="Sonuç: "+dogru+" Doğru, "+yanlis+" Yanlış"+"<br />";
        document.getElementById('rapor').innerHTML=rapor;
        
    }
}
var deger=window.setInterval('saniyeBaslat()',1000);
</script>
</head>
 
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="saniyeDurdur()" value="Durdur" />
<div id="saniye"></div>
<div id="uyari"></div>
<form name="formTest">
<fieldset class="radiogroup">
<legend>Soru 1: Aşağıdakilerden hangisi uygun değişken ismidir?</legend>
 <ul class="radio" style="list-style:none">
  <li>A) <input type="radio" name="s1" value="A" />  <label>case</label>  </li>
  <li>B) <input type="radio" name="s1" value="B" />  <label>try</label></li>
  <li>C) <input type="radio" name="s1" value="C" /><label>tree</label></li>
  <li>D) <input type="radio" name="s1" value="D" /><label>const</label></li>
 </ul>
</fieldset>


<input type="button" value="Cevapla" onclick="cevapla()" />
</form>
<div id="rapor"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the below function, variable `dogru and yanlis` are not declared. That's why your code was breaking.

```
function saniyeBaslat()
    
    {

       var dogru=0;
       var yanlis=0;

        saniye --;
        if(saniye >=0){
            document.getElementById('saniye').innerHTML=saniye;
        }else{
            window.clearInterval(deger);
            document.getElementById('uyari').innerHTML="Süreniz bitti! Sınav Bitmiştir Geçmiş Olsun";
            rapor +="Sonuç: "+dogru+" Doğru, "+yanlis+" Yanlış"+"<br />";
            document.getElementById('rapor').innerHTML=rapor;
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a variable inside a function, it wont be initialized until the function is run, in your case, until user click Ceplava button.
One example, this func will mess up because `saniye` is not declared when it is run. There are other lines that will not execute correctly because this reason.

```
function saniyeBaslat()

{
    saniye --;
    if(saniye >=0){
```

You need to move variable declarations outside a function, so it will be initialized even when the func is not run.

```
var soruSayisi=3;
var gelenCevap = new Array();
var dogruCevap = new Array("C",);
var dogru=0;
var yanlis=0;
var cevap=0;
var rapor="";

function cevapla()
{
```